# Eclipse plugin development - working with many files, marking MultiPageEditor as dirty throw exception

Tags: java, exception, eclipse-plugin

I am writing eclipse plugin. I've got MultiPageEditor in which i've got 5 pages. On first page there is an editor which extends GraphicalEditor(geEx), on second there are 2(logicInputEditor, logicOutputEditor) GroovyEditor's org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.editor.GroovyEditor). geEx is working with one file(e.g. first.qwe) and
 logicEditors are working with 2 other files(in.groovy, out.groovy). In
 geEx there is a code:

```
     @Override
                public void commandStackChanged(EventObject event) {
                        firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY);
                        super.commandStackChanged(event);
                }
```

When I edit file first.qwe MultiPageEditor know that something has
 been modified and marks it and allow to save file - everything is
 fine.

I add listeners to GrooveEditors:

```
     logicInputEditor.addPropertyListener(new IPropertyListener() {
                                @Override
                                 public void propertyChanged(Object source, int propId) {
                                         if (propId == IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY){
                                                 firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY);
                                         }
                                 }
                         });
```

I can't override commandStackChanged function, because GrooveEditor doesn't implement CommandStackListener.

Each time I edit something in one of GroovyEditors, the MultiPageEditor is changing its state to dirty - that's what i wanted, but also exception is printed on console. So - it's working as i want, but throwing and catching exception each time user type someting in editor is slow and generally bad.

The message is:

```
Problem trying to determine classpath of project Test:
 Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Test does not exist]
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newNotPresentException(JavaElement.java:495)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getPerProjectInfoCheckExistence(JavaModelManager.java:2287)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPerProjectInfo(JavaProject.java:1914)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getOutputLocation(JavaProject.java:1741)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.core.util.CompilerUtils.calculateClasspath(CompilerUtils.java:209)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.core.util.CompilerUtils.setGroovyClasspath(CompilerUtils.java:152)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.core.util.CompilerUtils.setGroovyClasspath(CompilerUtils.java:117)
 at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyCompilationUnit.buildStructure(GroovyCompilationUnit.java:260)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:526)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.makeConsistent(CompilationUnit.java:1100)
 at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(GroovyReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:60)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:89)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:788)
 at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyCompilationUnit.reconcile(GroovyCompilationUnit.java:423)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1231)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:133)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:108)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:89)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:87)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:151)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:206)
```

or:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 4 2012-08-13 20:33:29.402
 !MESSAGE Problem with build structure for in.groovy
 !STACK 1
 Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Test does not exist]
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newJavaModelException(JavaElement.java:505)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:246)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:526)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:255)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:241)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getJavaProjectElementInfo(JavaProject.java:1646)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2334)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:59)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.<init>(SearchableEnvironment.java:66)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.<init>(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:26)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:178)
 at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyCompilationUnit.buildStructure(GroovyCompilationUnit.java:338)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:526)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.makeConsistent(CompilationUnit.java:1100)
 at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(GroovyReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:60)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:89)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:788)
 at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyCompilationUnit.reconcile(GroovyCompilationUnit.java:423)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1231)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:133)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:108)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:89)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:87)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:151)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:77)
 at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:206)
 !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 969 2012-08-13 20:33:29.402
 !MESSAGE Test does not exist
```

The question is - how i can fix this? How should i send 'message' to MultiPageEditor, that one of GroovyEditors is 'dirty'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved - the problem was not in my code, but in GroovyEditor - if project nature is Java project nature(probably Groovy project nature will work too) everything is fine, otherwise GroovyEditor throws exceptions. I've reported bug to Groove Editor issue tracker and it has been solved so in next version everything should be fine. Now only solution is to add java project nature to natures of your project.